# Hide / show doesn't work as expected with jQuery (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I hide / show a html-node using jQuery selectors? See Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ruud00000/a1L8mwqn/). The intent is to hide the `text1` paragraph by clicking the first button and to hide the other text by clicking on the other button. Now, the node is hidden but then reappears. Please explain?

Here's the html part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="text1">text1</p>
<p id="text2">text2</p>
<form>
<input type="submit" id="hide1"></input>
<input type="submit" id="hide2"></input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here the JavaScript / jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide1").click(function(){
        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").show();
    });
    $("#hide2").click(function(){
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text1").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `submit` generally submits the form in the page to the server via the `HTTP` method you mentioned in the form or `GET` if you didn't mention any method. This generally results in browser going to the `target` page or refreshing if no target is mentioned. This is why the hidden text comes back, because everything resets when you hit the `submit` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options here.

1. Don't submit the form.  You can accomplish this by not using submit buttons.  To do this, set your input type to `button`, rather than `submit`

   ```
   <input type="button" id="hide1" value="hide"> <!-- note: input close tag removed/unnecessary —>
   ```

   You could also use `<button>` element:

   ```
   <button type="button" id="hide1">hide</button>
   ```
2. Stop execution after the button is clicked ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1L8mwqn/2/)).  This can be accomplished by preventing the default action for the event, or by returning false from the function:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#hide1").click(function(evnt){  // make sure to localize/name the event argument
           $("#text1").hide();
           $("#text2").show();
           return false;  // or evnt.preventDefault()
       });
       $("#hide2").click(function(evnt){  // make sure to localize/name the event argument
           $("#text2").hide();
           $("#text1").show();
           return false;  // or evnt.preventDefault()
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Otherwise, it submits the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can either change the type to button, or if you have a reason to keep them as submit, you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide1").click(function(e){
        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#hide2").click(function(e){
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text1").show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You're submitting the form which essentially reloads the page. the e.preventDefault() prevents that action.

Answer (score 2):

You use the form tag in the html and using button of type submit on it, so it post backs the page and so you see the labels both show up again after post back
this will fix your issue (change the button type to be button)

```
<body>
<p id="text1">text1</p>
<p id="text2">text2</p>
<form>
<input type="button" value='button1' id="hide1"></input>
<input type="button" value='button2' id="hide2"></input>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default behavior of a submit button is to post form. So, either you have to use preventDefault() method or you can return false to prevent form post if you want to keep those button as submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide1").click(function(e){
       $("#text1").hide();
       $("#text2").show();
       return false;
   });
   $("#hide2").click(function(e){
       $("#text2").hide();
       $("#text1").show();
       return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the a submit input type will do as said: submit the form, resulting in a page refresh. There is a way to prevent this default behaviour though:

```
// event.preventDefault();
$("#hide1").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // continue
});
```

preventDefault() will prevent the default behaviour to be triggered, in this case: submitting the form.